# Grammatical names and function

Tags: grammaticality, names, functions

What is the grammatical name and function of the italicised expression in the sentence

- She communicated gladly with a man *who was going to see his son in Lagos* and they exchanged numbers.

Comment: It's called a **relative clause** functioning as **modifier** of "man".

Comment: @Andrew You know very well that an 'answer' here would be most inappropriate.The question is ELL standard and a multidupe. And BillJ has given a paraphrased answer rather than a contradictory one. He has sought to help OP without compromising site standards of non-mediocrity.